# Microsoft SQL Azure HIPAA

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, san, hipaa

I am looking for some information on Azure.

1. Is SQL Server Azure is covered under HIPAA compliance?
2. Will MS sign HIPAA BAA?
3. How feasible it is to store the databases of more than one HIPAA compliant applications or for different clients on the same server ?database is SQL
4. when we talk about Server Farm, I am willing to host multiple client's DB on every server into separate instances, so is it possible?
5. Do MS have SAN ?
6. How do MS seperate the data of more than one HIPAA compliant app from each other ?
7. Can i get a trial account on MS Azure without credit card information to play around it for some time so that i can make sure and also convince my client to go with Azure.

Answer (score 5):

1) Is SQL Azure covered under HIPAA Compliance?

- Yes SQL Azure has HIPPA compliance, for more information about the Azure services that are in scope for HIPAA compliance look http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/trust-center/services/

2) Will MS sign HIPAA BAA?

-Yes, Microsoft offers the BAA to customers with Enterprise Agreements.

- For more information on BAA at Microsoft http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/trust-center/compliance/
- For more information on Enterprise Agreements http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/licensing-options/enterprise.aspx

3,4 and 6) I am not an expert in HIPAA compliant applications but there are guidelines available. http://www.bing.com/search?q=azure+hipaa+implementation+guide

7) Free Trial?

- Microsoft Azure offers a free 30 day trial with a $200 credit. However, you will need to input some information including a valid credit card.

Hope this helps!